# PHP, Two pages, option from one page shows one of three forms in the another page

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

I am trying to find how this one example was made. There is page A and Page B. Page A contains a form. In this form there is radio buttons for options, add, delete, and update... Choosing Add from Page A and pressing Submit, will open Page B.php with the form Add shown. Choosing Delete in Page A.php and submitting will show the same PageB.php only now with Delete form showing and not add. And so on. The question is, How is this done. 
I have heard of multiple forms on the same page and only the one filled out will be executed, but I cannot locate a way that the above described was done. Any help?

Comment: as long as you don't nest the forms in each other you can have as many as you wish on the same page at the same time. You donÄt have to show them at the same time. Javascript manaes the dynamic part usually.

Answer (score 0):

when you check PageB.php the code will be like below:

```
if($button == "delete") {
 //your code for delete 
}

if($button == "Add") {
 //your code for add 
}
```

and so on..

As per the form submisstion and what values you are getting different code will get executied on Pageb.php

Note: Above code is dummy only, to explain how the work flow could be.

Comment: I need to explain a bit more on what i am trying to do... One page, is affecting the other's form shown. I should say that I am beginner in PHP but would like to figure this out. So if pageA.php has delete radio button selected, pageB.php will load with Form delete showing. I assume from your $button example there is a $button is communicating between the two pages. So how do i communicate between the two pages to be able to get to the if statement

Comment: You must have form in pageA.php. and when this form is submit to PageB.php, Form will pass the values to PageB.php (via GET or POST method).

Comment: I think I have a possible path based on your answers. Thanks!